# How to access unmounted state from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access state's property when state isn't mounted yet.

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       test: 2,
       score: test * 2
    }
}
```

I wanna make `score` 4 but get this error:

> 'test' is not defined  no-undef

P.S `score: this.state.test` doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the `constructor`, so you can update your state without `.setState()` and without consequence, like that:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    test: 2,
  };
  this.state.score = this.state.test * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to define the variable before setting the state and then use it:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const test = 2;
  this.state = {
    test,
    score: test * 2
  };
}
```